# Efficiently making web pages from multiple servers

Tags: web-applications, web

I want to create a service that allows diverse web site owners to integrate material from my web servers into content served from their own servers. Ideally the resulting web page would only be delivered from the web site owners server, and the included content would be viewed as being part of the site by Google - which I think would rule out iframes or client-side Javascript to get the content from my server (although I may be wrong about that?).

Also the data wouldn't actually be updated that often, say once a day, so it would be inefficient to get the data from my web servers with every request. Finally, the method needs to be as simple as possible so that it is easy for web site owners to integrate into their own sites. Are there any good methods for doing this sort of thing?

If not then I guess the simple way is with iframes or Javascript.

Comment: it depends on what programming language this sites, which want to include your site, are made in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an incredibly broad question, but without more details:

Create a REST api for whatever data you're serving and cache it.

It's a well known interface for other site owners to consume, it's lightweight, and there are plenty of examples out in the wild that are probably specific to whatever platform you're targeting.

Comment: Yes, I realise it is a broad question - my objective in asking it was to make sure I had covered all the options and if anyone had any other ideas I hadn't thought of. And REST is an option I hadn't considered, so thanks for reminding me about it.

I think ultimately the solution is going to be to provide various options. I think my preference will be for generating HTML snippets via a REST interface that can either be included client-side via an iframe or integrated directly into a page by reading the snippet on the server-side, and encouraging the latter.

Comment: Yes, I realise it is broad, my reason for asking the question was to make sure I had considered all options. I think a REST api will be part of the solution - perhaps HTML snippets generated through a REST api that can be included via an iframe or integrated server-side. My only issue is making it easy for people to integrate on the server-side, when there will be many different types of server.

Comment: Answered twice sorry. First time it seemed there had been an error and my answer didn't appear straight away.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish an RSS feed so that other website consume it. Take a look at this [RSS Tutorial](http://www.mnot.net/rss/tutorial/)

Comment: Yes, RSS feeds are one of the options I am considering. I just want whatever technology I choose to be as simple as possible to integrate on the server side.